# Filtering based on a second data.table with a negation the command

Tags: r, data.table

I am very new to R and especially `data.table` and I'm stuck with the following.

I have 2 data.tables, say "Canteen" and "Saladconsumer".
The data.table "Canteen" contains the ID, date, time and items bought of every person.

The second data.table "Saladconsumer"contains the ID, date and time of people who have bought a salad and is basically a subset of "Canteen".

Now I'd like to filter "Canteen" by "Saladconsumer" so that I get the people that have bought a salad on that day and made an other purchase the same day in the canteen. Therefore the filtering must contain a negation: `Canteen[, ID]==Saladconsumer[, ID] & Canteen[, date]==Saladconsumer[, date] & Canteen[, time]!=Saladconsumer[, time]`.

I have only found examples for overlaps and merge/join if all the criteria are the same. It seems to be so simple but I just can't figure out what my mistake is...

```
NewDT<- Canteen[, Canteen[, ID ] == Saladconsumer [, ID ] & Canteen[, date ] == Saladconsumer[, date ] & Canteen[, time ] == Saladconsumer [, time ]]
```

This what the data looks like and what the results are I'm looking for:

```
Canteen     
ID  Date    Time
00b47c5d83a5490e860086eb080f1f50    26.06.14    12:36:29
00b47c898875483fb9fa0113d334e500    06.01.14    16:28:56
00b4cb6c666e2b8152174479545fcef2    29.10.14    12:57:16
00b4cb6c666e2b8152174479545fcef2    29.10.14    17:20:07
00b64cef0230b7480fc96dfcad9b8394    07.05.14    11:43:34
00b8b859987af5c89d90130d1206c579    03.01.14    13:35:15
0205996c0139e0b909903c2ebacb5a77    07.01.14    14:48:13
0205d25db373084f9bf8d431db8d3f9c    07.01.14    09:10:27
0205d25db373084f9bf8d431db8d3f9c    07.01.14    13:48:21
0208cfa78e51231cf30842ea0f8abdf4    10.04.14    10:06:43

Salad consumer      
ID  Date    Time
00b4cb6c666e2b8152174479545fcef2    29.10.14    12:57:16
0205d25db373084f9bf8d431db8d3f9c    07.01.14    13:48:21
020e53bd2076a9db4c9770662793602b    04.02.14    10:38:41
020ed0685aa70b543981cbb6a7f0c737    16.01.14    15:40:02
020aa996e0f4b6e886a82ce83d406e92    23.01.14    14:23:43
020ac1d718ff47f5aaa2d684434bae93    30.06.14    13:47:45
020b20874ae29027ddac149ab3d5a395    09.04.14    09:34:32

Results     
ID  Date    Time
00b4cb6c666e2b8152174479545fcef2    29.10.14    17:20:07
0205d25db373084f9bf8d431db8d3f9c    07.01.14    09:10:27
```

Comment: No, there is no such merge command. You can merge on all columns, create a 1/0 column to indicate which were matched and then filter to the opposite. Obviously, I can only explain it in those vague terms since you did not deign to provide an example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I would invite you to the tidyverse (which includes the package dplyr) and recommend a left join followed by an anti-join.

I also recommend looking at the RStudio cheat sheets on data manipulation: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/

This should do the trick (although I may have miss interpreted what you are looking for - in which case I am happy to help further):

```
library(tidyverse)

SaladPeople <- select(Saladconsumer, ID) %>% left_join(Canteen)
```

Now you have only the salad consumers at the canteen.  If I understand what you are looking for then you can do an anti-join:

```
yourData <- anti_join(SaladPeople, Saladconsumer)
```

Or as one would do this in the tidyverse:

```
yourData <- select(Saladconsumer, ID) %>% 
  left_join(Canteen, by="ID") %>% 
  anti_join(Saladconsumer))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for having a look at my problem. Unfortunately, I'm not receiving the results I was hoping/looking for. I added a subset of my data and the desired results. Maybe this clarifies it a bit better.

Comment: O it looks like I thought you wanted salad peoples purchases on the same day.  Please try the edited code.

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted!!!! In the results I have only the salad consumers second purchase of the day! Can you please reset the coding! I'd be very thankful!

Comment: I think the code should work. Let me know if it does not.